# How to Implement Text Bubble on Hover for Multiple Word Meanings?

Tags: android, hover

How to Implement Text Bubble on Hover for Multiple Word Meanings?

[image]

My Requirements

I would like to show a text bubble on hover over a given line with the other meanings.

Expected result

[image]

Please help.
For English words, Word can be "House", First meaning is "home" and other meanings could be "Apartment, Shelter"

Comment: Please help. I am able to solve the problem by LongClick method, but I would like to have "Hover" method